# Change boot drive after installing new SSD (M.2 to M.2)

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

My laptop has 2 M.2 slots. It came with a 128 GB M.2, but I recently bought a 256 GB M.2. I want to transfer (clone, migrate) the smaller M.2 to the larger one. Here is what I have done (Windows 10) thus far (Dell, Alienware 15 BIOS).

1. Installed new SSD in a second M.2 slot.
2. I cloned my OS and ESI partitions from C: (original M.2) to the new M.2 (called A:).
3. How do I change which drive the BIOS boots from? It's not a legacy BIOS. I cannot seem to find it in the BIOS, admittedly, I don't know what I'm looking for exactly.

Here is what my BIOS looks like. I have no idea if any of this makes sense.

[image: BIOS]

Comment: Cloning in a UEFI system requires cloning the ESP (EFI System Partition) as well.

Comment: Gotcha, I simply cloned the entire OS (using easeus). This includes the MBR, is there something I am missing?

Comment: If Windows was installed in UEFI mode (all factory installed Windows are) then there's no MBR, the drive has a GPT type of partitioning and an EFI partition where the bootloader resides.

Comment: Ah! I see that partition! If I clone that to my new SSD and remove it from the old one, will it boot via the new SSD?

Comment: No guaranteed but it should! After the process you need to open UEFI settings and assure the drive priority is set to the new drive. After that the firmware should be able to read the cloned EFI partition and detect the bootloader. How to do this depends on the specific hardware.

Comment: Should I physically swap the M.2 SSD spots? Would this fix the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a boot option from the firmware menu. Simply connect only the new drive and perform a UEFI boot pointing to that entire drive -- by default, Windows installs a fallback bootloader (`bootx64.efi`, which is what the firmware looks for when you point at a drive) that will handle those cases and add a proper Windows boot entry pointing to that drive.

Comment: You may not be able to boot if the boot loaders were setup incorrectly. What I would of done is setup OS on the new SSD, without connecting the old one, then transfer the content from the old one to the new one and boot from the new one.